# PostgreSQL: Creating a .sql file to insert data into a table the fastest way

Tags: database, postgresql, insertion, postgresql-9.1

I'm working on a project where I have to parse a bunch of .csv files, all of different formats and containing different kinds of data through some C++ functions. After that I extract data from the files and create a .sql file that can be imported in psql to insert the data into a PostgreSQL database at a later stage.

But I am not able to figure out the correct syntax for the .sql file. Here is a sample table and a sample .sql file reproducing the same errors I am getting:

Table Creation Code:

```
CREATE TABLE "Sample_Table"
(
  "Col_ID" integer NOT NULL,
  "Col_Message" character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT "Sample_Table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Col_ID" )
)
```

insertion.sql (after the copy line, fields separated by a single tab character)

```
copy Sample_Table (Col_ID, Col_Message) from stdin;
1   This is Spaaarta
2   Why So Serious
3   Baazinga
\.
```

Now if I execute the above sql file, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 2: 1 This is Spaaarta
        ^


********** Error **********
```

If it can help, I'm running a PostgreSQL 9.1 release, and all the above queries were executed through PGAdmin III Software.

Answer (score 1):

Three things to check:

- Is there actually exactly one tab characters between the columns? Spaces are a no-go.
- Are there more error messages? I'm missing *at least* one. (See below)
- When you force case sensitive table and column names you have to do this consequently. Therefore you must write this:

`copy "Sample_Table" ("Col_ID", "Col_Message") from stdin;`

Otherwise you will get theese errors:

```
psql:x.sql:1: ERROR:  relation "sample_table" does not exist
psql:x.sql:5: invalid command \.
psql:x.sql:5: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: 1 This is Spaaarta
        ^
```

With these things in place I can use your example data successfully.

**EDIT** Bug change: The questioner now has

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1 'This is Spaaarta'"
```

So something with the `1` is not OK.

My guess is, that this is an encoding problem. Windows with it's UTF-16 stuff might be the culprit here.

Debugging these kind of problems other the web is not easy, because to many semi-intelligent programs are in the line, most of them like to adjust "a few" things.

But first check a few things in psql:

```
\encoding
show client_encoding;
show server_encoding;
```

According to the pastebin data these should be the same and one of "SQL_ASCII", "LATIN1" or "UTF-8".

If they already are or if adjusting them does not help: Unix/Linux/cygwin has a `hexdump -C x.sql` program, post its output to pastebin. DO NOT USE the hexdump from any Windows editor like ultraedit - they have fooled me several times. When transferring the file to Linux be sure to use binary transfer.

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1   'This is Spaaarta'" - 
This is the error message I am getting now when executing from psql using the \i commmand. 

http://pastebin.com/WR6yN8Ar is the input file I used (note that it has column names and table name in double quotes)

Comment: @MHG: Using the `CREATE TABLE` from the question and the raw pastebin data _I_ get another error: `...ERROR:  end-of-copy marker corrupt`. After appending a newline to the `\.` line the file imports properly (each title is surrounded by `'`, but that's not a showstopper).

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin doesn't support executing COPY commands in the same way that psql does (or at least, it didn't the last time I tried it with version 1.14). Use psql to execute the script, or use INSERT statements.

Comment: for psql it works fine for me, after quoting the table and column names in the copy command.